# what's wrong with my jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

      $("a.g").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
      });

   });
   </script>

<a class="g" href="http://www.google.com/"></a>
```

still can click, I think I did something wrong in the selector?

Comment: [Nothing is wrong with it](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/67kkW/). Did you include jQuery?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Are you getting errors on the usage of $? That would point towards jQuery not being loaded correctly.

Comment: Are you realy sure you click on the right link (do you have some text in it to click on it???)

Answer (score 1):

its possible because you haven't include  jquery

include

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothig wrong with it, You need to [include jquery library](http://jquery.com/download/). And you are doing nothing in the event and you also have not text for anchor tag

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MeXvL/)

```
<a class="g" href="http://www.google.com/">aaa</a>​

$(document).ready(function() {

      $("a.g").click(function(event){
          alert("");
         event.preventDefault();
      });

});​
```